# SQL Server - Row Lock with JDBC

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

Is it possible to lock a single row on a SQL Server table using JDBC?

I'm using jTDS driver v1.2.7 and SQL Server 2005.

Trying with

```
UPDATE myTable SET timestamp=GETDATE() WHERE id='myid'
```

from SQL Server Management Studio the lock is acquired correctly on the row. I'm able to perform `SELECT` and `UPDATE` instructions on other rows.

If I try the same but using JDBC the entire table is locked.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why do you think the entire table is locked? What have you checked that tells you this?

Comment: It is unlikely that this has anything to do with JDBC or jTDS.  This is likely to be a result of the Table's configuration in SQL Server.  For instance, if [id] does not have an index on it, you will get this same effect.

Comment: post the exact Java code.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the isolation level of your session.

```
select session_id,login_name,program_name,
date_format,quoted_identifier,arithabort,
ansi_null_dflt_on,ansi_defaults,ansi_warnings,
ansi_padding,ansi_nulls,concat_null_yields_null,
case transaction_isolation_level  
when 0 then 'Unspecified'
when 1 then 'ReadUncomitted'
when 2 then 'ReadCommitted'
when 3 then 'Repeatable'
when 4 then 'Serializable'
when 5 then 'Snapshot'
end as transaction_isolation_level,
deadlock_priority
from sys.dm_exec_sessions
```

Maybe your SELECT becomes blocked because you are using READ COMMITTED.  The UPDATE will block only that single row as you leave opened the transaction.

Best Regards.

Comment: Setting `ReadUncomitted` solves the problem with `SELECT` instructions. Still can't update other rows