# SqlServer JDBC RowLock

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc

This is my problem:

I have a list of IDS in a table. More than one task concurrently need to read some IDS,  to retrieve some other data using that ID and to write some files.
Each task must work on a different set of IDS.
Obviously if something goes wrong I must rollback in order to allow another task to try to write the file again.

I use Java 1.8 (Spring Boot Framework) and SQLServer 2008 R2 with Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.1.

In my solution each task opens a transaction and locks the records it want to work on by performing an update with `ROWLOCK`

```
DefaultTransactionDefinition dtd = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
dtd.setIsolationLevel(DefaultTransactionDefinition.ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED);
dtd.setName(taskName);
TransactionStatus ts =transactionManager.getTransaction(dtd);

List<Long> result = jdbc.query("select top 3 * from D_TEST where STATUS = 0 order by 1",new LongExtractor());

for(Long l:result){
        jdbc.update("update D_TEST with  (ROWLOCK) set STATUS = 1 where ID_ROW = "+l.toString());
}
```

Then it use the list of IDS to perform other tasks if everything works fine close the transaction otherwise it rollbacks.

I would like that if another task starts while the first one it's still running when it asks for a set of IDS it will not recieved the locked ones.

The problem il that the query locks the entire table not only the rows. 
Where is my error? How can I lock only some rows?

Someone suggested ([SQL Server - Row Lock with JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098389/sql-server-row-lock-with-jdbc)) to change the isolation level to `ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED`, but in this case I read also the records being updated by the first task.
Moreover also with this isolation level the second task still stops to wait the that first transaction it ends.

Comment: I would bet the order by is causing a table lock, even though you're asking for the top 3 records;  is there an index on what it is sorting by?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, having done it before, you'll have to disable both *Lock Escalation* and *Page Lock* on indexes in SqlServer to force a row lock.

Doing so, however, has it's consequence.

Here is the [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29293/how-to-force-the-use-of-row-locks) for your reference.
Hope this helps.